# Looking for an old, possibly, 80's Asian scifi film with a female protagonist in futuristic armor

Tags: story-identification

Here's what I remember about the film. I think the title may have been something like "Xor" but Google reveals nothing. I think it had a mostly black cover with the title at the bottom, but I could be wrong.

I know it had an Asian-looking female who was possibly Chinese, Japanese, or Korean in black and white form fitting almost Power Ranger-style body armor, minus the helmet, with dark hair in a pony tail.

She fights a monster in a building like structure that maybe resembles a parking garage. The monster is humanoid-esque and has two tentacle like appendages that come out of its head, maybe.

There are also two possibly Asian-looking guys who drive a small boxy (possibly white) delivery van/truck around. One of them gets attacked and has a circular wound inflicted on his arm by the monster's tentacle appendage.

I know I rented the film at Blockbuster back when I was a kid, so it was released in America and dubbed. Probably it was from the 1980s but it could have been from the early 1990s? (or 1970s?)

Comment: https://www.imdb.com/find?q=xor&s=tt&ttype=ft&ref_=fn_ft

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think any of those movies are the one I'm thinking of. The title is just what I remember and it might not be exactly right, I"m only pretty sure it started with an X and was 3 letters long. Also note, that could just be an Americanized title too. Could also be Xon or some permutation of titles that start with X and are 3 characters long. I appreciate the input though!

Comment: You don't say, but I'm assuming this was a live-action movie?

Comment: Yes, it was definitely live action.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Could this be the 1991 film [Zeiram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeiram)? It's a live action film about a female bounty hunter who wears black and white armor fighting an alien creature which I believe does have tentacles. An English dubbed version was released in 1994.

Here's the original Japanese trailer:

Comment: I'm pretty amazed you came up with this. I know my details were sketchy, I was quite young when I watched this, but the monster looks about right, and so does the girl. This may be it. There's is also apparently a sequel to this film which may be the actual one I saw. I can't guarantee this is right yet, not until I find and watch it, but I have a good feeling about it. A much bigger lead than I've had before, that's for sure!  Thank you so much!

Comment: Arm wound scene: http://youtu.be/MLm-6-fhPNM?t=3202 and "Zeiram 2" http://youtube.com/watch?v=qSdjlVWqP2I

Comment: I tracked down the first movie and managed to watch it. Yea, this is definitely the movie I was thinking of. It's amazing I remembered as well as I did considering it's been like 25 or so years and I watched it maybe once or twice at most. It's even more amazing that you managed to help me figure it out. Considering how skewed everything looks from the perspective of a child, I was very curious how this movie really played out if watched from an adult perspective. Thanks again. You guys are awesome!